# Failure during analysis, Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

When I tried to scan my project using sonarqube it returned this error during analysis:

```
16:24:33  [ERROR] Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
16:24:33  org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
```

```
16:25:19  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
16:25:19  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:25:19  [INFO] Total time: 26:08 min
16:25:19  [INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-28T17:25:19+02:00
16:25:19  [INFO] Final Memory: 135M/2533M
16:25:19  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:25:19  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar (default-cli) on project nxdh-parent: Exception handling file: /data/jenkins/workspace/DHRD-81765-master-plan-migration/unit-conversion/src/main/java/datahub/measure/units/Mass.java -> [Help 1]
16:25:19  [ERROR] 
16:25:19  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
16:25:19  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
16:25:19  [ERROR] 
16:25:19  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
16:25:19  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
16:25:20  Java Result: 1
16:25:20  
16:25:20  BUILD FAILED
16:25:20  /data/jenkins/workspace/DHRD-81765-master-plan-migration/build.xml:260: The following error occurred while executing this line:
16:25:20  /data/jenkins/workspace/DHRD-81765-master-plan-migration/build.xml:495: Maven failed. Check log for details.
```